# Source for Bernstein's example for pairwise independence

Tags: independence, history

The German Wikipedia gives the following example for events that are all pairwise independent, but not jointly independent:

From four paper slips containing the numbers 112, 121, 211, and 222, one slip is randomly drawn. Consider the following events:
$$A_i = \mbox{"1 is at the $i$-th position"}\quad\mbox{ for }i\in\{1,2,3\}$$

Wikipedia gives "Bernstein (1927)" as source, but I have looked into

> S. Bernstein: "Sur l'extension du théoréme limite du calcul des probabilités aux sommes de quantités dépendantes." Math. Ann. 97, 1–59 (1927). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01447859

and did not find the example. I have also searched for "example", "soit", or "soient" in this article, but could not find the specific example. Is this the wrong reference? Does anyone know where this example actually stems from?

Comment: For a free (but not searchable) version see the first 60-odd pages of https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0097 - glancing through it, I did not see this example explicitly, though he did use phrases like "presque indépendent"

Comment: Meanwhile https://maa.org/sites/default/files/Stepniak-1-0734037.pdf gives the reference as p.47 of "S. N. Bernstein, Theory of Probability, 4th ed. (in Russian), Gostechizdat, Moscow-Leningrad, 1946"

Comment: @henry Thank you very much. It seems that the data concerning Bernstein's publications in the English Wikipedia is wrong: The "Теория вероятностей" appeared in 1934, not 1946, and it was reprinted indeed in 1946 as the 4th ed. Would you mind converting your comment into an answer so that the question can be marked as answered? Interestingly, Stepniak also proved that there are only two types of such examples for a sample space of size four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

https://maa.org/sites/default/files/Stepniak-1-0734037.pdf gives the reference as p.47 of "S. N. Bernstein, Theory of Probability, 4th ed. (in Russian), Gostechizdat, Moscow-Leningrad, 1946"

You commented  'It seems the data concerning Bernstein's publications in the English Wikipedia is wrong: The "Теория вероятностей" appeared in 1934, not 1946, and it was reprinted indeed in 1946 as the 4th ed.' and that 'Stepniak also proved that there are only two types of such examples for a sample space of size four.'